# Possible? Assign blade template to variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to assign a blade template to a variable in blade for code organization.

So basically let's say I have the variable `$response['actions']`

And the blade template admin.actions which contains

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="loadLeadComments('.$lead->id.')">
```

I want to basically be able to do something like

```
$response['actions'] = admin.actions (template)
```

so it renders that html inside of the variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `render()` [method](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_render):

```
 $response['actions'] = view()
                        ->make('admin.actions', array('lead' => $lead))
                        ->render();
```

The idea is the same as returning a view with data from a controller, with the extra `render()` method chained at the end.